Does beauty exist only in consciousness?
In a world without conscious beings, would beauty still exist? My belief is that beauty is purely subjective and can only exist in the mind. I don't think there is such a thing as objective beauty. But what have philosophers written about this topic? I would like to see some references.

There is a big distance between "there is no such a thing as objective beauty" and "beauty is purely subjective". If it was purely subjective how would people ever agree with others that some thing is beautiful or even understand how they are using the word? "Many attempts have been made to split the difference or incorporate insights of both subjectivist and objectivist accounts", see SEP, Beauty.

You have found the schism in philosophy between generic realism and some form of anti-realism. As such, it can be controversial for things like morals and other values like beauty as to whether or not they are real or not.
